# finding element by xpath selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, find, element

I'm using c# and selenium
i'm trying to find an element on a page which code is like this:

```
<form class="login box" id="signin-form" action="/signin" method="POST">



  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="login-email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
    <input id="login-email" class="form-control" type="email" name="login_email" placeholder="Email">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="login-password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input id="login-password" class="form-control" type="password" name="login_password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>

  <div class="login-password-meta">
    <label class="login-remember">
      <input class="checkbox" name="login_remember" type="checkbox">
      <i class="checkbox-icon icon icon-check"></i>
      Stay signed in
    </label>

    <a class="login-forgot" href="https://codeanywhere.com/forgotpassword">Forgot password?</a>
  </div>

  <button class="login-btn btn btn-md btn-secondary-outline" type="submit">Login</button>

  <p>Or sign in instantly</p>
  <ul class="login-social">
    <li class="login-social-google-plus">
      <a href="/google/authorize?state=login"><span class="sr-only">Google+</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="login-social-bitbucket">
      <a href="/bitbucket/authorize?state=login"><span class="sr-only">Bitbucket</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="login-social-github">
      <a href="/github/authorize?state=login"><span class="sr-only">GitHub</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="login-social-facebook">
      <a href="/facebook/authorize?state=login"><span class="sr-only">Facebook</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

I want to submit the form but I cant find the clickable element.
I've tried

```
FindElement(By.TagName("form")).Submit();
```

but nothing happend after code ran!just the page refreshed

and also

```
FindElement(By.ClassName("login-btn).click();
```

and it said it's not clickable

Comment: Can you successfully fill username/password input fields?

Comment: when you are trying to interact with that element , is it visible in UI?

Comment: An element is not clickable only when it is covered with some other element i.e is not visible.

Comment: @Andersson yes it fills the user and pas successfully

Comment: @cruisepandey yes its a login button

Comment: @DavoodKhobbakht : Check out the answers we have given.

Answer (score 1):

thank you all,all your answers were helpful. but i solved the problem myself..
the element was not clickable because it was hidden under another element and solved by makeing the web browser full screen by this code

```
WebDriver.Manage().Window.FullScreen();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to click using javascript :

```
public static void jsPress(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
FindElement(By.Xpath("//*[@id='signin-form']/button[@type = 'submit']").click();
```

also I would add `WebDriverWait` to wait until element will be clickable. I don't know which language are you using, but you can find the examples of `WebDriverWait` for your language in google. For `C#` it would be like this:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
var button = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(By.Xpath("//*[@id='signin-form']/button[@type = 'submit']")));
button.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach would be to **send enter keys** just after filling the form :

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);        
builder.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Else you can try with this **XPATH** :

```
//button[text()='Login']
```

**Code with WebDriverWait :**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Xpath("//button[text()='Login']"))).Click();
```

Different Approach :

To use Action class and move the focus to the particular element.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(element);
actions.Click().Perform();
```

This would be element in this case :  `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Xpath("//button[text()='Login']")))`